# Right skewed asymmetric Gaussian-like distribution

Tags: distributions, fitting, skewness, histogram

I am trying to find a possible candidate as a fitting function for a distribution that looks like the following

[image]

I know that this isn't a straightforward question, but I would like a simple function to start working with, before starting to optimize the procedure.

Comment: do you have grounds to believe that the apparent skewness is not just small-sample variability? Is "entries" = sample size?

Comment: @ChristophHanck : Thank you very much for your comment. Actually I expect this skewness. This histogram is the projection of a 2D histogram so I can see what I expect. And entries is actually the integral of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a family of distributions called the skew normal which includes an additional parameter for skewness. The normal distribution is a special case of the skew normal. Note that this distribution has limited flexibility on how much skewness there can be, with the skewness bounded between $-1$ and $1$ across the range of parameter values. For more info, read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).